# Akamai CCU SOAP API in soapUI

Tags: api, soap, soapui, soapfault, akamai

Has anyone been able to successfully use the Akamai CCU SOAP API?  I'm trying to use it with soapUI with the following (Java) WSDL: https://ccuapi.akamai.com/ccuapi-axis.wsdl.

When I run the sample request in soapUI with proper login credentials, the result I get is a SOAP error, specifically:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
     <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode>
     <faultstring>Exception: class com.idoox.soap.DemarshallException: Cannot recognize array "dimensions"</faultstring>
  </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Just wondering if anyone has encountered this and what you've done about it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We've used the Perl version from here:
[https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Akama](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net%3a%3aAkama)

I realize that doesn't help with Java but it can at least demonstrate that the SOAP api works.

Answer (score 0):

This might be happening because you need to set the array size. for example
  
 /images/myImage.png

Notice the xsd:string[1]
that is critical to making sure your soap array will demarshall correctly.